# Django Admin interface web service

Tags: python, django

I am trying to query the Django admin web interface programatically. Is there any standard way of doing this, or has someone written a Python wrapper?

Many thanks, Robert

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. What is "querying the admin web interface" as opposed to directly querying models?

Comment: I don't want to allow external access to the database - I want all access to be through the admin interface.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at [django rest framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework) or [django-admin2](https://github.com/pydanny/django-admin2)